# How to replace "\\" with '"' in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, titanium

Can any one help me in solving my issue.

```
Array = [
    { y: 0.02, label: \\5:37 A\\ },
    { y: 0.02, label: \\2:54 A\\ },
    { y: 0.02, label: \\1:00 A\\ },
]
```

Should replace `\\` with `"` expected Array/String should be as

```
[
    { y: 0.02, label: "5:37 A" },
    { y: 0.02, label: "2:54 A" },
    { y: 0.02, label: "1:00 A" },
]
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How is JavaScript supposed to do that? Is the "code" actually a string?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to update the actual source code? All decent IDE have reg exp based search and replace

Comment: You should describe your broader problem. Are you producing this string in the first place? Is your goal to somehow make the string insertable into a database or into an HTML fragment without the quotes breaking your string? If so, replacing quotes with any other character is not the right solution. You need to *escape* the the quotes, and then later unescape them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\\+
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `"`

https://regex101.com/r/aI4rA5/13

```
var re = /\\+/gm;
var str = '{ y: 0.02, label: \\5:37 A\\ }';
var subst = '"';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```